# Convert time in UTC format

Tags: php, time

I have following code:

```
$start_time="6:00 PM";

$end_time="10:00 PM";
```

The above time are according the countries `timezone i.e (Asia/Colombo, Asia/Adelaide...etc)`

And I want to perform the following calcuation:

```
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
$system_time = date('g:i A'); //Getting the system time according to the UTC timezone

    $time_left_for_discussion = $start_time - $system_time;

    if ($system_day < $day) {
        return "Upcoming";
    } else if ($system_day == $day) {
        if ($time_left_for_discussion <= 0 && $system_time <= $end_time) {
            return "Live";
        } else {
            return "NA";
        }
    } else {
        return "NA";
    }
```

Here the $system_time is according the UTC timezone. Now I want calculation for $time_left_for_discussion so for that I need need to convert $start_time and $end_time in UTC format for correct calucation.

Hope you got my point.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/). P.S. I'm not the downvoter. Just answering your question.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: @JohnConde : Ok I'll modify my post

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @SalmanA : Check the modified post

Comment: @JohnConde : check the modified post

Comment: If I get your point correctly then you do not need any conversion and long as you have two **timestamps**.

Comment: @SalmanA: The system_time is in UTC format so for correct calculation I want starttime and endtime also in UTC format. Starttime and endtime I am submitting from dropdown box of half and hour of interval and have stored in database.

Answer (score 0):

Try the dateTime class.

```
$date = new DateTime("2010-07-05T06:00:00Z");
$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Comment: Giving error : Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Answer (score 0):

use can use [getOffset function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.getoffset.php)
For the timezone conversion you can use this as an example

```
<?php

$userTimezone = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');
$gmtTimezone = new DateTimeZone('GMT');
$myDateTime = new DateTime('2009-03-21 13:14', $gmtTimezone);
$offset = $userTimezone->getOffset($myDateTime);
echo $offset;

echo date('Y-m-d H:i', $myDateTime->format('U') + $offset)
?>
```

This will convert the time from GMT timezone to Newyork timezone.